# How can I alter the curve of a radial gradient in CSS?

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I'm trying to achieve this gradient. What I don't understand is the curvature of it and I'm not sure on how to replicate it:

[image: gradient]

What I have so far:

[image: attempt]

and my code for the gradient:

```
radial-gradient(at top left,#629a92 36%,#02d2a0 67%, #fff 11%)
```

However I'm not sure how this gets stretched to the end of the screen. I haven't used `radial-gradient` much before so I feel like I'm missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the source of the site you're trying to replicate?

Comment: Maybe an SVG would work better for this.

Comment: @jhpratt this is a design that was given to me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to also adjust `background-size` of the gradient:

```css
body {
 height:100vh;
 margin:0;
 background-image:radial-gradient(at top left,#629a92 36%,#02d2a0 67%, transparent 67.5%);
 background-size:120% 100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Or adjust the radius:

```css
body {
 height:100vh;
 margin:0;
 background-image:radial-gradient(120% 100% at top left,#629a92 61%,#02d2a0 92%, transparent 92.5%);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If it's a `linear-gradient` inside a curved shape you can try to use multiple background. The idea is to create the `linear-gradient` and above it you add the a `radial-gradient` with transparent color to be able to see the first gradient.

```css
body {
 height:100vh;
 margin:0;
 background-image:
   radial-gradient(120% 100% at top left,transparent 92%, #fff 92.5%),
   linear-gradient(135deg, #51a595 0%, #3fcfa2 100%);
 }
```

Comment: This has a pretty glaring stepped edge in Firefox and IE.

Comment: @TylerH yes fixed, it was because of the last color stop

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I mean https://i.stack.imgur.com/efUE8.png I think it is just how Firefox and IE implement the radial-gradient.

Comment: @TylerH yes because gradient aren't antialising and to fix this we need to keep a small difference between the last colors stop, it should be fine now

Comment: @Spacebear5000 I have updated my answer if you need a linear gradient withint a curver shape ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you look carefully it is not a radial gradient. It is a linear gradient inside a radial shape. If I were you, I would do a SVG shape—mine is just for using as example—and apply it to the gradient.

Like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.main:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #51a595;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #51a595 0%, #3fcfa2 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#51a595', endColorstr='#54bb9b',GradientType=1 );
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#mask");
          clip-path: url("#mask");
}
```

```html
<svg>
   <defs>
    <clipPath id="mask">
      <ellipse cx="0" cy="-1400" rx="2200" ry="1500"></ellipse>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at radial-gradient on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient), it can take 2 percentages before the `at top left` for its size. We can make the first larger than 100% so it will extend beyond the screen on the x axis and put the second percent to 100% so it ends at the bottom.

```
radial-gradient(
  200% 100% at top left,
  #629a92 36%,
  #02d2a0 67%,
  #fff 11%
);
```

This should result in what you are looking for

```css
.head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(
    200% 100% at top left,
    #629a92 36%,
    #02d2a0 67%,
    #fff 11%
  )
}

.body {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="head"></div>
<div class="body"></div>
```